# How to add a new entry under a given XML tag in python

Tags: python, xml

I need to modify an xml file in python; specifically I need to add a new entry under the `video` tag. For instance, having something like this

```
<sources>
    <programs>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
    </programs>
    <video>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
        <source>
            <name>Dir 1</name>
            <path pathversion="1">/path/to/dir1/</path>
            <allowsharing>true</allowsharing>
        </source>
        <source>
            <name>Dir 2</name>
            <path pathversion="1">/path/to/dir2/</path>
            <allowsharing>true</allowsharing>
        </source>
    </video>
    <music>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
    </music>
    <pictures>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
    </pictures>
</sources>
```

I need to create a new entry under `<video>...</video>` as follows:

```
<source>
    <name>Dir 3</name>
    <path pathversion="1">/path/to/dir3/</path>
    <allowsharing>true</allowsharing>
</source>
```

and update the original xml file. What would be the best practice to do so?

Comment: You'll want to use an XML parser in most cases, but for very simple cases like this, where the structure of the documents is consistent and well-known, you can just do a text replacement... replace `</video>` with your new markup plus `</video>`

Comment: @kindall very interesting, thanks! It'd be nice to have this using `xml.etree.ElementTree` as well though. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to insert.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')

root = tree.getroot()
insertLoc = root.findall("./video")[0]
start1 = ET.Element(insertLoc)
insSource = ET.SubElement(start1, "source")
insName = ET.SubElement(insSource, "name")
insName.text = "Dir 3"
insPath = ET.SubElement(insSource, "path")
insPath.attrib = {'pathversion':"1"}
insPath.text = "/path/to/dir3/"
insAllow = ET.SubElement(insSource, "allowsharing")
insAllow.text="true"

insertLoc.append(insSource)

print(ET.dump(tree))
```